# Index Out Of Range (Range Is Variable)

Tags: vb.net, indexing, datagridview, integer, datagridviewcolumn

So I'm trying to return all the column names in my datagridview. The code below returns the column names except at the end, I a message stating `Index was out of range` I assume this is because I have less than 500 columns in my datagridview.

The 500 could in theory be any amount, some might only have 20 columns, others might have 300 columns.

How would I go about clearing up this error?

```
Dim c As Integer
    For cn = 0 To 500

        c = c + cn
        'Debug.Print(cn)
        Debug.Print(DataGridView1.Columns(cn).Name)

Next cn
```

Comment: `For cn = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1` perhaps?

Comment: *especially* if the columns can vary, use the Columns.Count-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Index out of range" exception can happen when you are trying to access a member of collection under index that doesn't exist

Lets take your example - you getting error here `DataGridView1.Columns(cn)` because your `cn` has a value which doesn't exist in `DataGridView1.Columns`. For example, if you have 2 columns, your indexes are `0` and `1`. If you try to ask for `DataGridView1.Columns(2)` - you will get this exception. So, as mentioned above in comments, when dealing with collections you either use `For Each` loop or you use `For... count -1` loop

This is correct code:

```
For i as Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
    Debug.WriteLine(DataGridView1.Columns(i).Name)
Next
```

Example of `For Each`

```
For Each s as String In myStrings  ' myStrings can be List(Of String)
    Debug.WriteLine(s)
Next
```